# Confused with BundleID and Prefix when submitting my app to the iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

Xcode5's Archive Manager says my product Identifier is "EdAndJ.SomeAppName".
This is what the "Bundle Identifier" says in the project summary.
I do not work for a company... just me.

I'm trying to submit to iTunes Connect.  It says:

- Your APP ID Prefix is:  C58H638D3X  (I changed some of the number but you get the idea).
- What Explicit BundleID do you want: I put in "EdAndJ.SomeAppName" but is says: An App ID with Identifier 'edAndJ.SomeAppName' is not available. Please enter a different string.

I go to [the developer site](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifiers/bundle/bundleList.action) and see that the app was somehow registered!  But I can't seem to "Validate" it from Xcode 5. I get the following error: "No application records were found."

Any help would be appreciated.

-Ed

Answer (score -2):

1. Go to developer.apple.com and log in to the Member Center.
2. You should see the Developer Program Resources, click 'Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles'. Navigate to iOS Apps -> Identifiers -> App IDs
3. Click on the + button in the top right corner.
4. In App Description, enter a name for your App. This name will not be displayed later. It is only visible to you
5. Unter App ID Suffix, choose 'Explicit App ID' and enter your unique App ID. Apple recommends to use a reverse domain name style like 'com.EdAndJ.SomeAppName'
6. Make sure to make the right ticks at the App Services section.
7. Hit Submit, hit Done.
8. Make sure the entered App ID matches the Bundle ID in your App. It has to be exactly 'com.EdAndJ.SomeAppName'. Prefix is not necessary.
9. Go to iTunes Connect, login and create a new app. Here you have to enter the same App ID: 'com.EdAndJ.SomeAppName'.

Hope this helps

Comment: Man I feel like an idiot. I can't even follow your step2.   Cannot find "iOS Apps" in developer.apple.com.   when I do (I hope you can point me to what you meant), one of my questions is: Where does the prefix come into play?  It is not used in the Xcode Bundle ID but iTunes Connect seems to imply that it will be used in the BundleID...

Comment: (not sure how I go here but)...  https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifiers/bundle/bundleList.action shows:    Name:Some App Name     Prefix: XXXXXXXXX     ID: EdAndJ.SomeAppName           But I still cannot Validate the Archive from Xcode nor can I create it in iTunes Connect.   @daydr3amer... thanks for your help...

Comment: I'm going to close this topic and start a new one now that I have a little more understanding of what's going on.

Comment: I should have been more precise. Step 2: Go to developer.apple.com, top right corner, klick Member Center and log in. Now you should see the Developer Program Resources, click 'Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles'. In the next menu you should now be able to see 'iOS Apps', click 'Identifiers'. Now you continue with step 3. Don't worry, the first time is the worst :P

Comment: Ah I saw you already found it. Before you can validate the archive from Xcode, you first have to create the app in iTunes Connect. Why can't you create the app? At what point does it fail?

Comment: Here is another approach: Try adding a wildcard App ID in developer.apple.com. Instead of choosing explicit App ID, choose wildcard and enter '*' without the ' where it says Bundle ID. (Do not delete the old App ID 'EdAndJ.SomeAppName'). Now go to iTunes Connect and you should be able to choose the wildcard ID. Where it says Bundle ID Suffix, enter 'EdAndJ.SomeAppName'